# Hook "wp_trash_post" executing multiple time in case of bulk trash products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently using hook wp_trash_post to trigger my custom API when a WooCommerce Product is trashed.
This is working fine for the case of single trash.
But, in case of Bulk trash this event is executing multiple times. for example if 3 products are selected to trash then this event will trigger 3 times.

I need different event for Bulk Trash which will execute one time but having all of product ids.
Hopefully it is clear to understand.
Please Help!

Comment: Can you share a snippet? I wonder if it will be feasible to prevent the function from running with a nonce, timeout, or other valuation?

Comment: i am using this code https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_trash_post/#div-comment-4641 and there will be API call in if and else part.

Comment: Did you discover a solution? 

If not, and I don't mean to be a prickly pear, but, it conventional to share your code (obfuscate proprietary items as needed) so folks who are wishing to help you don't waste their time offering solutions that aren't actually applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Your API call must be withing the foreach loop and is therefore being run foreach post ID. You can capture the IDs in a variable and execute your API call after the if and foreach statements are complete:

```
function wpdocs_trash_multiple_posts( $post_id = '' ) {

    $trashed_ids = [];

    if ( isset( $_GET['post'] ) && is_array( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $_GET['post'] as $post_id ) {
            $trashed_ids[] = $post_id;
        }
    } else {
        $trashed_ids[] = $post_id;
    }

    // Do something here, $trashed_ids array 
    // contains either one, or several IDs
    
}
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'wpdocs_trash_multiple_posts' );
```

Comment: Sorry if i did not explain it well, i am doing the same as you mentioned. the problem is hook 'wp_trash_post' triggering multiple times by default. like first time it come to function and send api call. Now, it should not come again to this function and execute the same process again.

Comment: I see. If you'd like to obfuscate your API call and post your snippet, I can take a second look. It won't be very efficient for me to guess at what you're doing and provide suggestions based on my guesses.

Comment: i have added one line in your answer code $this->api_curl_function( $trashed_ids );